# How can I use ExceptionNotifier in my models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, exception

I have a transaction in one of my model. When something go wrong, I want to be notified.

If it would be transaction in controller, I would simply do:

```
begin
  (my transaction...)
rescue => exception
  ExceptionNotifier.deliver_exception_notification(exception, self, request, data)
end
```

But I want to do similar thing in my model, passing `nils` as `self` and `request` does not help. What can I do about it?

Answer (score 1):

In our project, we use it differently:

For model, we create an initializer in project_directory/config/initializers to add it to
ActiveRecord::Base.

```
class ActiveRecord::Base
  include ExceptionNotifiable
end
```

Doing this, all models exception will invoke ExceptionNotifier email as per our configuration.

For controllers, we include it in our ApplicationController so if there is an exception in any controllers, we will receive an email.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  include ExceptionNotifiable

  .....
end
```

For transaction in the controller, i will do:

```
class MyController < ApplicationController

  .....
  def create

    MyModel.transaction do
      .....
    end

  end
end
```

Without rescuing the exception, the ExceptionNotifier will be called automatically.

Hopefully it helps.